# Any ideas to embed a (SSH) terminal into some HTML5 presentation systems (ex, reveal.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Every time I am giving a talk about programming or some toolset, I like to have some live and practical demo. My current work-around is to have one presentation program with another terminal program (let's assume the demo is console-mode.).

I am thinking to use HTML5 presentation systems like [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) or [impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js). And I know there is an awesome chrome extension: [Secure Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo). Anyone got idea to embed a shell/terminal like Secure Shell into something like **reveal.js** or **impress.js**?

Comment: Have you tried an iframe? Or does the terminal not live in a tab, on a custom URI scheme?

Comment: How about [Sheir.tv](http://shelr.tv/)?

Comment: @Bergi Secure Shell is a chrome extension and I have no idea how to use iframe with it.

Comment: @steveax Sheir.tv looks great. Unfortunately, it doesn't fit to my goal.

Comment: Embeding this will be fairly complex as it uses NativeClient. Even if you do embed it with NativeClient, it will still only be supported by chrome, even then it will be sketchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw a presentation recently which used [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) to do this. It looked very cool.

Comment: If i use shellinabox, i need to have server running in remote machine.  is there any way I just click on a web page button it should open a tab (embeded ssh terminal) asking user to enter host and uname/pwd

Comment: I think what you want is a shell client in a web browser. [Termius](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/termius-ssh-client/fjcdjmmkgnkgihjnlbgcdamkadlkbmam?hl=en) may be what you want. It has a chrome app. Now it turns to develop applications based on different OS directly.